# I am looking for sample Google Checkout code for .Net

Tags: asp.net, google-checkout

I am looking for sample .Net code to handle the order processing from google checkout. I will be using the HTML Api as it does not require SSL. I found this [Custom Order Processing Tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Custom_Processing_How_To.html) but it is using Java. I eventually want to use [Google Subscriptions](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Beta_Subscriptions.html) and I am hoping that a sample Order processing code would give me enough information to complete my Google subscription integration.

**EDIT**

Is there an open source end to end solution which implements Google Checkout subscription and order processing using .Net?  I am hoping that I can implement my own by looking at an example. I have a very simple task, google button click goes to google checkout, customer pays for subscription that is charged a monthly amount. Google sends a response or notification which my system processes and updates my database.

Comment: I have to say this... It concerns me that you're doing an application that's presumably a shopping app, and you don't want to use SSL.  You should be using SSL for ANY form that collects potentially private data, including customer name, street address, etc.  It's not required, but it's good practice to protect your customer's data.

Comment: +1 David, I will implement SSL at a later date after the testing the first phase of this project.

Comment: @David - Google Checkout gathers the customer name, credit card data street address, etc., not the website of someone implementing Google Checkout.  So, while SSL is probably still a good idea for the implementing website, Google Checkout is doing the heavy lifting here in regards to protecting sensitive data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google provides sample code for using their Google Checkout .NET API versions 2.4 and earlier for order processing:

http://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-dotnet-sample-code/downloads/list

It's not fully featured sample code, but it should be enough to get you going without having to resort to dealing with XML directly.

Version 2.5 of the Google Checkout API no longer requires SSL/https for handling notifications.  Google has not yet provided any .NET sample code for that scenario.  Through trial and error, I created an ASP.NET MVC sample application that handles Google Checkout notifications from the 2.5 API:

http://www.capprime.com/software_development_weblog/2010/11/29/UsingTheGoogleCheckout25APIWithASPNETMVCTheMissingSample.aspx

Those are the only samples I am aware of and I've spent hours searching.

See also: [C# example for Google Checkout replies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662394/c-example-for-google-checkout-replies/)

Answer (score 0):

Google provides code samples.

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/samples/Google_Checkout_Sample_Code_NET.html

Comment: I have looked at the above link and there is no clear was of implementing Order Processing API and Notification API. The unclear part for me is how to handle the call that comes to the Callback url.